# Error: Unable to load celery application. The module tasks was not found

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I'm trying to get celery up and running on Heroku as per instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku)

When I try to run "heroku local" however it fives me the following error:

```
10:05:42 PM worker.1 |  Error: 
10:05:42 PM worker.1 |  Unable to load celery application.
10:05:42 PM worker.1 |  The module tasks was not found.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: It should be noted that I have a module tasks.py in my root directory with the following code in it:

```
import celery
app = celery.Celery('example')
@app.task
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the folder?

Comment: yes. nothing is in it.

Comment: I know it's pretty, late but can you share the command you are using to start?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, I think you need to populate the **init**.py in your project folder (same folder as celery.py). You can follow [Celery official documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

This is what you should add to **__init__.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Hope this helps.